# EF 4.1 POCO template generator conflicting with ClassObjects.Context.cs

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I've been using EF 4.1 and the POCO template generator.

I love and hate EF. I love the time I save. I hate maintaining the EDMX file.

But while keeping the EDMX in sync with the database has been a challenge, I'm now overwhelmed by the POCO generator. Up until now, the POCO generator has created POCO's for me and kept the ClassObjects.Context.cs empty and non-conflicting.

After my most recent refresh I have had constant problems with "Amiguity between 'perseus.DataLayer.accounts' and 'perseus.DataLayer.accounts'.

I get this error for every POCO.

I'm on the edge of panicking as I recommended and owned the maintenance of EF. I've spent a couple days on trying everything from database refreshes to deleting all items from the EDMX file and reloading them from the database.

Nothing has made a difference. I have no clue what has suddenly changed from the last few months of *relative* stability. I'm seriously lost as to what I can do from here.

[image]

Comment: It would help if you showed us what was actually conflicting.  We have no idea what they are based only on their names.

Comment: @Mystere Man, I wasn't sure what I could show since ALL objects are conflicting. I added a screenshot of the build errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you have not disabled the code generation strategy.  click on the designer background and check the properties tab, the first item is Code Generation Strategy.  This should say None, and not Default.

Comment: Your guess was a pretty good one, but the Code Generation Strategy is set to "NONE". Sloppy of me not to point that out. But you wouldn't have guessed from the tools behavior. Clearly it's not behaving as it should.

Comment: @DaveA - you said you re-added the entities.  Did you try deleting the entire .edmx file and starting with a new one? Then adding the code generation template?

Comment: thats the distance I haven't gone. I'm reluctant b/c a complete re-start means not learning what is wrong and (inevitably?) running into the problem again.  But I'm getting close to the point where it feels like I should. Your input gives me the feeling there's no where else to go.

Comment: @DaveA - Sorry, I thought you just wanted to solve the problem, not figure out why.  You need to figure out where the conflicts are.  Did you try doing a build clean and rebuild?  Did you do a search for two copies of the entities?

Comment: honestly both. Thanks for the suggestion. I think I should just re-create it and move on.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the edmx manually is difficult and error prone. I would suggest copying what you have off to another location then letting the tool regenerate the edmx for you. Compare the two.

I worked with some DB2 entities that I had to manually sync and had constant issues. The tool would clobber my changes and I would have to manually replace that with working code.

If at all possible, don't modify the edmx code yourself. If you must, make the changes, copy those off to a text file in the project for tracking/safe keeping.